# Adding a navigation drawer to an existing project

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm a beginner in Android. I have a project with multiple activities and I need to add a navigation drawer to this project instead of a normal menu. I added a new navigation drawer activity, but it doesn't show in my previous activities.
Should I add something to my existing activities?
All the tutorials I have watch use fragment while I use AppCompatActivity.
So I don't know how can I add it to my project.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You have to use fragment, it does not work with `AppCompatActivity` because you can't display an activity inside an activity

Comment: Post what you have done because the way you describe it can be interpreted many ways

Comment: You've to create multiple instances of appbar for every activity and then in all the appbar xmls , link the same drawer xml present in menu directory. This is what I did in one of my example projects.

Answer (score 0):

to do that, you have to use fragments instead of activities. fragments are easier to work with navigation drawers than activities. 1st you have to create a main activity for navigation drawer. Change your other activities to fragments. Then you can have navigation drawer in all the fragments. Refer below video it has everything you want. if there is any problem ask. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SUvA1fXaKw